# AR not working properly in my iOS app on iOS 14 and Xcode 12.3 with world tracking performance is being affected by resource constraints

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, augmented-reality, arkit

The airplane does not stay at a fixed position and moves around even when I keep my device still. I am using iPhone 7.

This is the warning that I get on the console when I run the default template code provided by XCode with the airplane:
"ARWorldTrackingTechnique <0x103a2a3e0>: World tracking performance is being affected by resource constraints [1]"

I have looked at all of the questions posted on stackoverflow and apple's site based on this error and none of them have a solution. One of the solution provided was to make the app available only on orientation mode but still it does not work.